# Error initializing controller while testing angularjs with karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, controller, karma-runner

I'm trying to test my application with Karma but I get following Errors:

```
minErr/<@/home/usr/webui-ng/src/client/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:5
loadModules/<@/home/usr/webui-ng/src/client/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3859:1
forEach@/home/usr/webui-ng/src/client/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325:7
loadModules@/home/usr/webui-ng/src/client/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3824:5
createInjector@/home/usr/webui-ng/src/client/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3764:3
workFn@/home/usr/webui-ng/src/client/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2150:9
```

These are my files:
hello.js

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "Ari";
    $scope.sayHello = function() {
        $scope.greeting = "Hello " + $scope.name;
    }
})
```

hello.js - test file :

```
describe('Unit: MainController', function() {
// Load the module with MainController
beforeEach(module('myApp'));

var ctrl, scope;
// inject the $controller and $rootScope services
// in the beforeEach block
beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
    // Create a new scope that's a child of the $rootScope
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    // Create the controller
    ctrl = $controller('MainController', {
        $scope: scope
    });
}));

it('should create $scope.greeting when calling sayHello',
    function() {
        expect(scope.greeting).toBeUndefined();
        scope.sayHello();
        expect(scope.greeting).toEqual("Hello Ari");
    });
```

});

As you can see, I've already loaded the module, as the solution was in [Controller undeclared in Jasmine test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22331970/controller-undeclared-in-jasmine-test).

What else could it be? I haven't found much about these errors on the web. I would be very happy to finally find an answer for that.

Comment: What is a angular.js version you are using?

Comment: Please ensure that the hello.js (the real code) is really included in a karma.conf.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As runTarm mentioned, the path in the karma.conf.js was not set to the **actual path** of the script file (hello.js).